# Sanyasin initiation

Tags: rituals, sannyasa

I am interested in becoming a Sanyasin but live in the UK. Apart from the Hare Krishna are there any Sanyasins in the UK and if not where could I get initiation

Comment: You can contact them here .http://bhaktimarga.co.uk But don't know about enlightenment of Swami Vishwananda. Analyze well before choosing guru.

Comment: You want to take Sanyasa in which Sampradaya?... (Advaita, Dvaita, Shaiva, Sri Vaishnava, Gaudiya Vaishnava etc.... )

Comment: If you are interested in Advaita then you can contact the Vedanta Center here:  http://www.vedantauk.com/

Comment: Most that are worthwhile will not give sannyas initially. You must live for a number of years as a student brahmacharya before sannyas is given.

Comment: You have to come to the shaiva or vaishnava  or advaita ordvaita or gaudiya  sampradaya first. You should learn the sampradaya from root level. Adhere to the principles laid. Do penance for years.